# Reading files into program

Tags: c++, input, output, file-handling

I am attempting to write a program that:
-reads a text file, then puts it into a string
-change each letter in the string by subtracting 4
-outputs the changed lines

I understand how to input/output files. I do not have much more code than that and am rather stuck as this is a very new concept for me. I have researched and cannot find a direct answer. How do I input each line of the original file into a string and then modify it?

Thank you!

```
// Lab 10
// programmed by Elijah

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    fstream dataFile;
//Set the file "coded" as the line input
    dataFile.open("coded.txt", ios::in);

//Create the file "plain2" as program output
    dataFile.open("plain2.txt", ios::out);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream inFile ("coded.txt"); //explicitly input using ifstream rather than fstream
    ofstream outFile ("plain2.txt"); //explicitly output using ofstream rather than fstream
    string str = "";
    char ch;
    while (inFile.get(ch))
    {
        if (ch!='\n' && ch!=' ')
        {
            //do your manipulation stuff //manipulate the string one character at a time as the characters are added     
        }str.push_back(ch); //treat the string as an array or vector and use push_back(ch) to append ch to str
    }
}
```

This more explicitly opens both an input and output file stream then creates an empty string and unitilized character. `inFile.get(ch)` will return true so long as it is not at the end of the file and will assign the next character to `ch`. Then inside the loop you can do whatever you need to do with `ch`. I just appended it to the string but it sounds like you will want to do something before appending.

In your case the get(ch) will be better than a getline() or >> method because the get(ch) will also add spaces and tabs and other special character that are part of the file which getline() and >> will ignore.

If by string-4 you mean the characters that are 4 less in the manipulation line you can use:

```
ch = ch-4;
```

Note that this could give results different than what you expect if ch initially was 'a', 'b', 'c', or 'd'. If you want wrap-around use ascii manipulation and the modulo operator (%).

Comment: Thank you, this works great! One question: is there a way to maintain the line breaks included in the original input file?

Comment: If you mean newlines, I think those will be stored to ch just as any other character. If not, please clarigy

Comment: @Elijah You might accidentally be modifying ch by subtracting 4 which you wont want to do if it is a newline or space. see revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your dataFile, therefore you either have to create a second `fstream` or process the strings first and afterwards use the same `fstream` for output.
String reading:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/
String modifying:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/
And what do you mean with "String - 4"?